# If a load is placed onto a DC motor, will the current increase?

Tags: current, motor, dc, dc-motor, load

When a load, such as a weight on string, is placed into a motors axle, will this cause the current to increase?

Comment: Is the voltage constant? Are you saying the motor has the string wrapped around its axle, and is *lifting* the weight when it rotates? Specifically, the weight is *not* being lowered by the motor?

Comment: Yes, sorry, The weight is being lifted by the shaft of the motor and the voltage is constant.

Comment: That certainly depends on how you feed the motor.

Comment: Yes if the voltage drive is constant. Then the current demand needed by the motor will increase. Now with that said there may be a limiting case where the weight is so small and the increase also small that there may be no increase in current if motor is running current to overcome the rotational inertial is large in comparison.

Comment: Follow up question. If I was to increase the magnetic field of the permanent magnets and then lift the weight up, would this increase or decrease current?

Comment: Increasing the magnetic field strength will slow the motor and increase its torque at any given current. Then increasing the weight will increase the current again. So yes, this would increase or decrease the current, unless it remains the same.

Comment: Just to make things clear, you can't "increase the magnetic field" of a PMDC motor. Brian is assuming you actually replaced the permanent magnet located at the stator of the DC motor with another magnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The load decelerates the motor.
2. Every DC motor works like a generator. As it slows down, it does less. The generated voltage opposes the input voltage.
3. The current increases with the generator voltage dropping.
4. As the current increases, the motor produces more torque.
5. A new equilibrium will be reached at lower RPM and higher current.